# Modify existing private VBA sub?

Tags: vba

I wrote a macro along the line:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
   Some code
End Sub
```

It worked fine while tested, and was then released. Following user feedback, now I need to modify the macro but cannot uncover it as it would not appear in the VBA editor.

Is there a way to unhide the Sub, modify it and hide it again (the distribution requires macros to be as foolproof and well hidden as possible)?

Many thanks in advance,
K.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SuperUser. A little more information will help get you an answer quicker; a private sub is only hidden from the macro list a user can view when selecting the Macros function, the macro should still show up in the project collection. Where is the macro held? On a sheet or on This Workbook? Has the project been locked?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. The macro is held in one worksheet of the specific workbook AFAIK (probably This Workbook) but of course now it's hard to reproduce :-( The workbook is locked when distributed but being the author, I edit the macros in unlocked state and the description refers to unlocked state.

Comment: do you know which worksheet the code is tied to? The `Worksheet_Activate` is for a specific worksheet, and would not appear in a separate module

Comment: Do you not have a backup development copy of your project? Why not work from there and then repackage it for user consumption?

Comment: Are you sure it's not in `PERSONAL.xlsb` - check the VBA Editor

Comment: An Excel macro?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you have hidden your code by selecting the block of code, right clicking and pressing Hide in the right-click menu. This will leave the sheet visible but hide the code. To undo this, select the sheet where the code should be, right click and select View Code from the right-click menu, this will bring the code back.

Hiding the code of a Private Sub means that if someone doesn't know about it they'd think there was no code, as they'd have no way to locate it. Rather than hidding your code:

*Go to VBA Project Properties under Tools*
[image: VBA project]

*Then on the Protection tab select Lock project for viewing, and add a password*.
[image: Protection]

Then close your Developer window and relaunch it. Be sure to give the project password to other members of your team, as there's no way to get around it.

Now your code will only be accessible to those with the right password, but your code will be visible to those who need it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, this is not the case. I opened the worksheet's code using View code, put my macro there (mixture of snippets off the Web and my own code), tested, protected as you describe, and sent out. Once I tried to modify, the worksheet code (after unprotecting) appears blank but the macro works. In fact, in the VBA window I can add a brand new Worksheet_Activate routine... odd... . If this is of any importance, I work in Excel 2003 (and 2003 VBA) for compatibility reasons, to cover most form recipients.

Comment: Very odd. The only thing I know of that could make it still run is if it's still there, as in hidden. So you've unlocked the project, and tried double clicking on each sheet to get the code page up, then right clicking it in the Project Explorer and clicking View Code, and the code still isn't showing up in the code page? Forgive me for asking this, but can you double check you're looking at the right project? With my Personal book on the list I often end up being in the wrong project :\

Comment: Also, I've done a quick test and it's possible to have more than one Worksheet_Activate code in a single sheet, so we don't need to worry about that bit at least :)

Comment: It is most definitely the same workbook (only one I work on currently), and I did as you describe, to no avail. Thanks for the latest reply, however, it seems to work, I added the old + new code to a new Worksheet_Activate Sub, this time not private. Untidy but will have to do. Still curious where the bug comes from...

Comment: Very odd indeed, like I said, Private doesn't hide the sub in the Project, only in the Macro list. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Worth the attempt anyway :-) 10x